# How to display/change the owner of a file on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, permissions

Is there a way to display the owner of folders and files from the command line in Windoews 7 command prompt?

Can you change the owner of a folder or file to some "arbitrary" user which is not your own username?

I have some folders (and files) that are **probably** left over from an app that I have removed. If I try to view the contents of the folders I am that told I don't have permission to do so, even if I am running as an "Administrator".

I can "Take ownership" (I assume this will be successful but haven't tried it yet) of the folders (files), but if I need to revert the ownership to the previous owner, I need to know the username of the original owner, and I need to be able to "give ownership" to that user.

Is it possible to do this from the Windows command prompt (or if not, from a GUI-Tool)?

Comment: See here for a solution purely using cmd.exe:
[Get ownership information from command line by using wmic](http://superuser.com/a/1103541/429608)

Answer (score 26):

You can take ownership from the command line via the [takeown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.10).aspx) command and via the Windows GUI.

You can view the owner of a file/folder by using the [DIR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121(v=ws.10).aspx) with a /q parameter

You can view (and take) ownership via the Windows GUI by right clicking the object in Windows Explorer (file or folder), selecting **Properties** and then navigating to the **Security** tab.  On the **Security** tab, click the **Advanced** button and on the subsequently displayed **Advanced Security Settings** dialog, navigate to the **Owner** tab.

Once you have taken ownership of a file/folder, Windows does not track the previous owner, so there is no way to revert back to the previous owner.  Also, there is no concept of ownership or file permissions if you are working with a file system type that does not support these extended attributes such as FAT16, FAT32, exFAT, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `wmic` to query the ownership information like this:

```
wmic path Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting where Path="C:\\windows\\winsxs" ASSOC /RESULTROLE:Owner /ASSOCCLASS:Win32_LogicalFileOwner /RESULTCLASS:Win32_SID
```

Don't use `dir` since the ownership info may be clipped, as with this example directory.

To get an output formatted with `DOMAIN\USER` you can use the following batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Escpe the backslash with \\
SET ESCAPED=%~f1
SET ESCAPED=!ESCAPED:\=\\!

wmic path Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting where Path="!ESCAPED!" ASSOC /RESULTROLE:Owner /ASSOCCLASS:Win32_LogicalFileOwner /RESULTCLASS:Win32_SID > "%temp%\wmi.tmp"

for /F "skip=2 delims=€" %%G in ('type %temp%\wmi.tmp') do (call     :process_wmioutput "%%G")
goto :continue
:process_wmioutput
SET UNDELIMITED=%1
SET DELIMITED=!UNDELIMITED:  =€!
FOR /F "delims=€ tokens=10,12" %%G in ("!DELIMITED!") DO (ECHO %%H\%%G)
exit /B

:continue
```

Comment: How can this work with a full directory of files? For example, as a replacement for `DIR /Q`

Answer (score 4):

[`cacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732245(v=ws.10).aspx) and [`icalcs`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) can edit permissions and [`takeown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.10).aspx) allows to take ownership. AFAIK they exist in Windows 7 as well. Typically, once you do a [`takeown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.10).aspx), you follow it up with [`cacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732245(v=ws.10).aspx) or [`icalcs`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to grant yourself permissions to the object.

Microsoft’s security model doesn’t permit to *give* ownership to someone, only to *take* it. That way an admin (or otherwise privileged user) cannot take ownership of a file inaccessible to her directly, access or modify it, and give it back to the original owner without notice to the original owner.

Edit: Credit goes to [Art](/users/114461) for the description of the use of [`takeown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: cacls does not allow one to change or view the owner of a file.  You would use [takeown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.10).aspx) to do that. Typically, once you do a takeown, you follow it up with calcs or icacls to grant yourself permissions to the object.

Comment: Thanks, you're entirely right. I guess it shows that I've been out of the Microsoft world for too long to remember those things. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I know this is old, but I thought that I would add that you can set the owner to someone else using icacls. icacls <path> /SETOWNER <name> works. Of course you need to be the owner or have appropriate permissions before you can do that so you could enact the scenario of taking ownership and giving it back provided you have the ability to take ownership in the first place.

Comment: Last time I checked, Windows prohibits the transfer of ownership to another account except to the one that performs the transfer.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - According to this:  [Restoring 'TrustedInstaller' as owner for executable in Windows folder](http://superuser.com/q/890310/144147), it appears that it will work. I haven't tried it myself yet.

Comment: @palehorse did `icacls <filename> /setowner <username>`. got `<filename>: Access is denied.`. was running `cmd.exe` in `Asminstrator: ` mode. Filename was like *foo.png*, username was like *John*. Filename was taken from `cmd.exe`. Username was taken from `explorer.exe` GUI and matched the directory name in the `\Users` directory.

Comment: I can confirm all three exist in Windows 7 Professional (not checked on Home).  `Cacls` declares itself to be deprecated in favour of `Icacls`.

Comment: @KevinFegan: Is this maybe related to `TrustedInstaller` being a system user? It's not like those can take ownership back themselves if you want to modify one of their files or benefit from the notice on the change of ownership. Plus they trust administrators by definition – unlike the human owner of a regular user account.

Comment: *Microsoft’s security model doesn’t permit to give ownership to someone, only to take it.* I am sorry, but this is just nonsense. I am doing exactly this constantly on all sorts of Windows server (back to 2008 R2) and client (back to Windows 7) operating systems. Once you are the owner of a file, you can assign yourself the full range of permissions to do *everything* with it, including changing the ownership to any other user.

Answer (score 3):

`SubInACL.exe` allows you to set the owner.  The syntax looks something like:

```
SubInACL /file filename /setowner=NewOwner
```

If you don't have it, you can [download it from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=23510).

Of course you have to have the rights to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If using just `DIR` in the Microsoft world, try the `/Q` option.

For example:

```
DIR *.xlsx /Q
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of Art's answer.

Comment: I'm dealing with some files that are listed as being owned by `...` when I run `dir /q` - even from an elevated cmd window.