# Restoring 'TrustedInstaller' as owner for executable in Windows folder

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, permissions

After changing the ownership of executables in the Windows directory (`explorer.exe`, `regedit.exe`, etc.), I can't seem to change it back to `TrustedInstaller` using `icacls.exe`. Using the GUI method (*Properties → Security → Advanced → Owner*) works fine though.

Doing the same thing to any other file under Windows, that is *not* an executable, works fine. Tried the same under safe-mode, no luck.

These are the 2 basic commands I'm using:

```
takeown /F C:\Windows\explorer.exe /A
icacls C:\Windows\explorer.exe /setowner "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"
```

---

*Edit*: Forgot to mention I'm receiving the error 'Access is denied'.

```
C:\Windows\System32>takeown /F c:\Windows\explorer.exe /A  
SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "c:\Windows\explorer.exe" now owned by the administrators group.

C:\Windows\System32>icacls c:\Windows\explorer.exe /setowner "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"  
c:\Windows\explorer.exe: Access is denied.  
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

Comment: There are [tools](http://betanews.com/2015/03/14/windows-repair-3-0-debuts-pro-version-new-pc-fixes/) that claim they can solve problems like this.  You say it doesn't work but don't elaborate.

Comment: My bad, I'll try to be more clear. The action fails, claiming access denied. 
Sadly, installing external tools isn't an option. 
Portable tools like sysinternals or setAcl should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command works only after granting full permissions to the Administrators group, i. e.:

```
icacls c:\Windows\explorer.exe /grant Administrators:f
```

Even granting 'Modify' doesn't seem to be enough for some reason.

Comment: All answers here does not work anymore if original owner is `TrustedInstaller`. Tested on both `takeown` and `icacls`. Only direct editing through the context menu of the `Windows Explorer` has worked. Seems MS step by step injecting it's telemetry everythere without option to scriptingly disable it.

Comment: For example, such permissions can not be easely retaken from the `C:\Windows\System32\CompatTelRunner.exe` or something similar.

Answer (score 8):

So the title says restoring TrustedInstaller.

Seems there is a missing part; removing the added Administrators group permissions.

```
takeown /F "C:\Windows\regedit.exe" /A
/F - file to become owner of
/A - means it will set the users group (ie. Administrators, not userxyz)

icacls "C:\Windows\regedit.exe" /grant Administrators:F
/grant - will add permissions
:F - Full Control

icacls "C:\Windows\regedit.exe" /setowner "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"
/setowner - new owner

icacls "C:\Windows\regedit.exe" /grant:r Administrators:RX
/grant:r - will set permissions (removing higher ones)
:RX - Read and Execute
```

Reference:
https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re adding (what isn’t already in the question or the accepted answer).

Comment: He is restoring the rights for `Administrators` to the original ones. Remember that `Administrators` has been assigned full permissions before, which is clearly against Microsoft's intentions, so this should be reverted after the action has been done. Hence, I think his answer is valuable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you discovered in your answer, is that setting the owner of a file requires a special permission, specifically "take ownership." The reason the ACL editor GUI is able to set the owner anyway is that it enables the `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege` [privilege](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/privileges), which allows overriding that access check. Programs running as administrator have this privilege, but they have to explicitly enable it before using it, and apparently `icacls` doesn't.

Conveniently, processes inherit the privileges of their parent by default, so if you can enable that privilege for the command prompt from which you invoke `icacls`, the utility will have the privilege enabled too and will be able to set the owner. You can use my open-source utility [SprintDLL](https://github.com/Fleex255/SprintDLL) to call the appropriate Win32 functions to enable the privilege in SprintDLL's parent process (the command prompt):

```
SprintDLL call kernel32.dll!OpenProcess /return native /into prochandle (int 0x400, int 0, slotdata parentpid); newslot native token; call advapi32.dll!OpenProcessToken /return int (slotdata prochandle, int 0x20, slotptr token); newslot block luid = int 0, int 0; call advapi32.dll!LookupPrivilegeValueW /return int (nullptr, lpwstr "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege", slotptr luid); newslot block privs = int 1, slotdata luid, int 2; call advapi32.dll!AdjustTokenPrivileges /return int (slotdata token, int 0, slotptr privs, slotsize privs as int, nullptr, nullptr)
```

If it works, the output will say all three called functions returned 1. You will then be able to use `icacls` as you originally attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here (tested in Windows 7 64-bit).

Ensure you've started your command prompt in elevated mode (aka: "Run as administrator").

Comment: Only tried it on 32 bit, I'll test it on 64 shortly.
Command prompt is indeed elevated, I even tried running it as 'NT Authority\System' using psexec.

Comment: Did you modify the permissions for the Administrators after changing ownership? Also, what file did you try?

Side note, had the same behavior on win7-64bit.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on 64 bit system (and my issue)...

```
icacls c:\Windows\SysWOW64\usercpl.dll /grant Administrators:f  
icacls "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usercpl.dll" /setowner "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"
```

/setowner - new owner

Answer (score 0):

#### Experimenting with `C:\Windows\System32\CompatTelRunner.exe`

##### 1. Change the *ownership* to `Administrators`

Hit <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd`, hold down
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
<sup>1</sup>

Then run :
<sup>2</sup>
`dir /q CompatTelRunner.exe`

Expect the response to contain a line like :
`<Date> <Time> <bytes> NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaCompatTelRunner.exe`
(Unfortunately, `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` gets cut off.)

This response shows that the current owner is `TrustedInstaller`.

Next run :
<sup>3</sup>
`takeown /f CompatTelRunner.exe /a                                       (1)`

Now expect the response from `dir /q CompatTelRunner.exe` to be :
`<Date> <Time> <bytes> BUILTIN\Administrators CompatTelRunner.exe`
showing that the owner has been changed to `Administrators`.

##### 2. Extend the *access permissions* of the `Administrators`

Run :
<sup>4</sup>
`icacls CompatTelRunner.exe`

Expect the response to contain the following two lines :
`NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)`
`BUILTIN\Administrators:(RX)`

This response shows that the `TrustedInstaller` still has Full control
(even though it's no longer the owner), while the `Administrators`
group still has only Read & eXecute permissions (even though it's now
the owner).

Then run :
`icacls CompatTelRunner.exe /grant Administrators:f                      (2)`

Now expect the response of `icacls CompatTelRunner.exe` to contain the
lines :
`BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)`
`NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)`
showing that the `Administrators` group now also has *Full control*.

##### 3. Set the ownership *back* to `TrustedInstaller`

Run :
`icacls CompatTelRunner.exe /setowner "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller"      (3)`

Expect the response from `dir /q CompatTelRunner.exe` once again to be
:
`<Date> <Time> <bytes> NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaCompatTelRunner.exe`
showing that the owner has now been restored to `TrustedInstaller`.

##### 4. *Reset* the access permissions of the `Administrators`

The only thing that remains to be *restored* is to set the permissions
of the `Administrators` group back to just *Read & eXecute* :
`icacls CompatTelRunner.exe /grant:r Administrators:rx                   (4)`

Expect the response of `icacls CompatTelRunner.exe` now to contain the
lines :
`BUILTIN\Administrators:(RX)`
`NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)`
showing that the access permissions of the `Administrators` group has
been restored.

##### 5. Why you got `Access is denied`

Is it clear by now why you got `Access is denied`?
– The reason is that when you took ownership of the file,
*you still did not have full access permissions* on it.
So when you tried to set the ownership back to `TrustedInstaller`, you
didn't have the necessary permissions to do so, and hence got
`Access is denied`.
Taking ownership of the file is the correct first step, because
otherwise you are not allowed to extend your permissions.

##### 6. What's the point?

Running the above commands (1), (2), (3), (4)  – in that order – will
restore your operating system to how Microsoft sets it up.
This is true regardless of whether the access permissions of this file
were *already* restored or not.

*So what's the point?*
– Well, I never used to run the commands (3) and (4).
And I don't intend to do so in the future either.

Why should I?
– As long as I trust my administrators (including myself), I
don't really see any reason to restore things to being
*the Microsoft way*.

Answering this question has still been worthwhile as I have learned to
take ownership and change access permissions of a file.
And to understand the difference between the two.

#### References

- [`DIR /Q` – Display the owner of a file](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [`TAKEOWN.exe` – Take ownership of a file or folder](https://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html)
- [`ICACLS.exe` – Change file and folder permissions - display or
  modify Access Control Lists (ACLs)](https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html)
- [`ICACLS.exe` at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls#icacls)
- [A *much* shorter answer to the question asked](https://superuser.com/a/1321278)

---

<sup>1</sup> Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> makes the
command prompt open *as administrator*.

<sup>2</sup> The command `dir /q <SomeFileName>` displays the owner of
the file `<SomeFileName>`.

<sup>3</sup> The flag `/f` is needed to indicate that what follows
next is the name of the file/folder.
The flag `/a` gives ownership to the *Administrators*.

<sup>4</sup> ICACLS stands for Integrity Change Access Control ListS.